# How to make a TextArea change its height according to its content?

Tags: java-me, lwuit

I have a TextArea and I want its height to grow dynamically according to its content : so there is no scrollbar needed. How to achieve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setGrowByContent(true);` on the `TextArea`.

Comment: How to know the maximum number of characters, columns, that the TextArea can contain in a row ?

Comment: There is no limitation for set the text on TextArea. If you want limit the character means use `setMax(..)`. And you can set the no of columns and rows on TextArea constructor.

Comment: My problem is that I want the "columns" parameter of the TextArea constructor to be close than the phone device screen display width. So how to know the maximum number of characters that a display width can accept ?

Comment: AFAIK you can't get maximum character in a single line on TextArea. Its automatically re-sized for different resolutions.

Comment: True. You don't need the maximum characters. We generally just use a number like 20 which is big enough to "grow" the growth is more of a function of the layout manager. E.g. BorderLayout CENTER would receive all available space where NORTH/SOUTH would receive all available width. BoxLayout Y would receive all available width and preferred height etc...